# Matlab : select Random values form different arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have different arrays :
    1.They may have common values or not.
    2.They may have same length or not.
 I want to select N Random values from all these arrays, which from each array at least one value were selected.

for example I have these arrays:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5]
B=[4 5 6]
C=[7 8 9 10]
```

and my Random values could be:

```
D=[1 8 4 3 10]
```

the point is the result array shouldn't have duplicate values and select values from all arrays.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can try to help you.

Comment: How is it relevant that some of these values are common? Wat kind of randomness do you need (i.e. distribution)?

Comment: That's not a sufficient description to implement it. Equal probably for each array? Equal probably for each element? Or something else?

Comment: @Daniel : equal probably for each array and each element.

Comment: That is impossible unless all arrays have the same size.

Comment: I just want random values,just No duplicate and from all array.

Comment: To describe a random variable, you have to define two things. 1) The possible events (which you did) and 2) The probability for each event, which you did not define. A common case for 2) is equal probability for all possible events, but this contradicts equal probability for each number.

Comment: @Ana.IM - You can't choose `N` values among all arrays unless each array has at least `N` values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be more specific about which probabilities should be fullfilled. My solution will select an `array` by equal chance. Then I select an Element of it by random and delete the value from the chosen `array` as it shouldn't be picked any more. It will be added to the solution if it is a new value.

In your case probabilities are difficult to predict as values could repeat multiple times in the same and other arrays.

```
        clc, clear all, close all
    A=[1 2 3 4 5];
    B=[4 5 6];
    C=[7 8 9 10];

    x = []; % Solution
    n = 5; % Number of Random Values

while numel(x)<n

    if numel(x)<3           % Which array to chose from
        a = numel(x)+1;     % First get a value from each array.
    else
        a = randi(3,1);     % After 3 picked values select random arrays.
    end

    switch a
        case 1
            if ~isempty(A)
                i = randi(numel(A));    % Select random entry from A
                z = A(i);                % Save random entry
                A(i) = [];               % Delete selected entry
            end
        case 2
            if ~isempty(B)
                i = randi(numel(B));    % Select random entry from B
                z = B(i);                % Save random entry
                B(i) = [];               % Delete selected entry
            end
        case 3
            if ~isempty(C)
                i = randi(numel(C));    % Select random entry from C
                z = C(i);                % Save random entry
                C(i) = [];               % Delete selected entry
            end
    end

    if ~ismember(z,x)
        x = [x,z];  % Add to the solution if it is a new value.
    end

    if isempty(A) & isempty(B) & isempty(C)
        disp('Not enough different values');
        return
    end
end

disp(x);
```

Comment: How does this code guarantee to select at least one element from each list?

Comment: I overread that part. Will fix it in a second. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The solution will now break if for the first 3 entries there is no new value to be picked in an array or if you enter an empty array. However it will work if there are at least 3 unique values in each array.

Comment: +1 because this answer answers the question, but I would be very careful using such a constructive process. It implements a very odd probability distribution which probably not reflects what is required, but as the question does not say anything about the probability distribution, this question is as good as any other possible answers.

Comment: Thanks, but it's impractical when the number of array's increase. I use 3 arrays for my example. I have more than 50 arrays.

Comment: In that case it would be helpfull, if you provide the code which generates the arrays. Also if you can explain the usecase.